# Slack ephemeral message from global shortcut

Tags: slack-api, slack-dialog

I want to post an "ephemeral" message to a user after a modal is submitted via a global shortcut. But in Slack, [global shortcuts](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/shortcuts) don't have the context of the channel the user had focused when the shortcut was invoked. The API body on the *interactivity* endpoint doesn't contain any channel information.

Yet there is this example from the Asana shortcut:

[image: Example of Slack ephemeral message from global shortcut]

How are they able to respond with an ephemeral message to the channel that the user had focused when they invoked the global shortcut?

Comment: Can you confirm this is a global shortcut and NOT message shortcut? Are there some links/details to elaborate this issue in detail?

Comment: I can confirm this is a global shortcut. The documentation says that doing this is not possible. I have no _other_ links because nothing can be found on Google about how to do this.

Comment: The other way I can think of is that you have a dedicated channel and you post the ephemeral message to that channel, or DM it to the user directly.

Answer (score 1):

As per slack, this functionality may be coming soon:

> We are exploring options to add channel context to global shortcut payloads where appropriate, with user opt-in. Please contact us with your desired use case.

https://api.slack.com/interactivity/shortcuts/using#coming-soon

May be they have given early access to Asana, or as mentioned in the comment, they are using some fixed channel work flow.